# why the return statement of override equals() method has to use alternate && and ||?

Tags: java, overriding, equals, hashcode

I saw the code below online. the class override the Object class's hashCode() and equals method. I was just wondering why the return statement of equals() method has to use alternate && and ||? can i just use && all the way through? is there any particular reason why it has to use alternate && and ||?

```
class Person {

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Person guest = (Person) obj;
    return id == guest.id
            && ((firstName == null ? guest.firstName == null : firstName.equals(guest.firstName))
            || (firstName != null && firstName.equals(guest.getFirstName())))
            && ((lastName == null ? guest.lastName == null : lastName.equals(guest.lastName))
            || (lastName != null && lastName.equals(guest.getLastName())));
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + id;
    result = prime * result
            + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
    return result;
}



}
```

Comment: This `equals` method is very hard to understand as it is now. I suggest breaking it into multiple if statements to make it more readable.

Comment: It doesn't have to.  I've never seen it done this way.  The person who wrote it flipped the targets on the equals calls.  I think it's an excess of caution and a dearth of understanding.  If guest is null the method returns false before it ever reaches that mess.  So why worry about the possibility that guest can be null?  Probably a fix for something else that's badly done.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, this method has logically wrong code, which may give unexpected outputs. But, hey @TonyStark, you can always ask Jarvis!

Comment: its so hard to learn how to code, its impossible for beginners to know what we are seeing is right or wrong :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both disjunctions can be replaced with the first operand of `||`, since the second operator just covers the second alternative of the tenary operator again (assuming the getter returns the field value)

```
 id == guest.id
        && (firstName == null ? guest.firstName == null : firstName.equals(guest.firstName))
        && (lastName == null ? guest.lastName == null : lastName.equals(guest.lastName));
```

But I recommend rewriting it as

```
id == guest.id
        && Objects.equals(firstName, guest.firstName)
        && Objects.equals(lastName, guest.lastName);
```

Answer (score 1):

The OR condition is used depending of the value of first name or last name respectively taken into account if they are `null` out not. But that condition is already checked in the second part of the ternary ? : Operator, so you can remove the OR part. The result will be the same

```
((firstName == null ? guest.firstName == null : firstName.equals(guest.firstName)) || (firstName != null && firstName.equals(guest.getFirstName())))
```